# why does removing float collapse my background button image?

Tags: css

I've searched and seen people write about float:clear, but i think I'm having the opposite problem?

My button background image works with float, but when I remove float, I only see the button value text with 0 margin and the background image behind it-the button image is being cropped.  I'm sure this is a very basic thing, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong?

I can put a span around the button text and mess with margins to make something work, but I'm not sure if that is the right way to fix this?

I can include code if needed, but I'm hoping this is just an obvious thing to someone.

Comment: Could you post code? What do you mean by "button"? <button>? <input type="button"/>? A div with CSS to style it visually like a button?

Comment: Can you post the HTML tag of that button? Is that display:inline||block ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only thing you to do is remove `float` to cause the problem then my guess is you need to add `display: block` to your button's css.

Comment: That was it-can't believe I missed that. Thanks!